# I want a selected item in combobox on formlogin to be automatically changed in Main form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have 2 forms:

- first the `loginform`, which contains `combobox1` that user will select
- and then the Main form, which will be display the selected item in `combobox1` on  the `label1` in `loginform`.

I tried :

```
label1.Text = "welcome, "+ (new formlogin()).comboBox1.selectedItems.ToString();
```

,but I've got an error with message:

```
Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.
```

Comment: you should capitalize the `S` in `Tostring`

Comment: does your exception have any other information?  what you've shown so far doesn't tell us much.

Comment: i have capitalized it...
but it still got the same error "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application.."

Comment: can you show us a screenshot of the exception maybe?

Comment: `new formlogin()` is a new instance, not the form the user is seeing.  You need a reference to that instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this... but this is the simplest way that I can think of:

Add this property into your FormMain:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Then, in your FormMain's load event:

```
label1.Text = this.UserName;
```

Then, from your FormLogin when you show the MainForm:

```
FormMain form = new FormMain();
form.UserName = combobox1.selectedItems.ToString();
form.Show();
```

Comment: it still had the same error = "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue, the application.."

Comment: From which line is that error is throwing at? Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: im sorry ,i forgot a semicolon..
its working fine now...
Thank you very much,,,u really helped me a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the error message in the screenshot said

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

That means that you're trying to use an unsubstantiated object

---

It is most likely is that your `formlogin` constructor doesn't actually instantiate `combobox1.selectedItems`, thus causing the error.

But what i think you might be trying to do is the following

```
label1.Text = "welcome, "+ this.comboBox1.selectedItems.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

In your Main Form you first declare loginForm and show it:

```
formlogin logForm = new formlogin();
logForm.FormClosing += loginFormClosing;
logForm.ShowDialog();
```

Then declare a new Method

```
public void loginFormClosing()
{
  //This method will be called when the loginform is closing
  //declare a variable in your loginform class and call it here like:

  label1.Text =  "welcome, "+ logForm.selectedItem.ToString();
}
```

I'm sure there is a better and smarter way to do this. But this is how I do it.